# Bash passing arguments to a command

Tags: linux, bash

I need to execute in Bash the following command:

```
beeline -u "${DATALAKE_NAMENODE_HIVE}:${DATALAKE_NAMENODE_PORT_HIVE}/pcgexp; -hiveconf ....  -f ..... "
```

The thing is that in Linux the ';' character is indicator of end of the command and I also need to use environment variables. How can I do this?
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try putting the text for each flag in quotes making sure that the ; is enclosed within the quotes. So, -u "..." -hiveconf "..." -f "..."

Comment: You can specify the environment in from of the command like `env_var=value command arguments`.

Comment: A quoted semicolon, as you have here, has no special meaning to `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @ilkkachu is on the money, as is chepner's comment -- quoted semicolons have no special meaning, and quoted arguments make more sense than a quoted SET of arguments.

That said, another handy way of handling arguments in bash is to use arrays.

```
declare -a b_args=()

b_args+=( -u "${DATALAKE_NAMENODE_HIVE}:${DATALAKE_NAMENODE_PORT_HIVE}/pcgexp;" )
b_args+=( -hiveconf "...." )
b_args+=( -f "....." )

beeline "${b_args[@]}"
```

This helps with manageability -- you can comment out a part of the argument list, have a clear view of what's being set without having a super long command line to figure out.

In a normal (non-associative) array, arguments are always output in the numerical order of their index, which always increments as you append to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just quote the parts you need (changed to shorter var names):

```
beeline -u "${var}:${anothervar}/pcgexp;" -hiveconf ....
```

If `var` contains `foo`, and `anothervar` contains `bar`, that would give these arguments:

```
-u
foo:bar/pcgexp;
-hiveconf
....
```

Quoting the spaces will make the string a single argument, which may or may not be what you need.